# Why does the Logical Or not work in my function

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i modify the blow sample code to not only check for empty Keys but also null and undefined.
I tried

```
(obj[key] !== '' || obj[key] !== null || (obj[key] !== undefined)
```

but that broke it and didnt work at all so if i use either condition it will work but not when all together. So i am wondering how i can combine it all 3 conditions in this code.

```js
const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
  let newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if      (obj[key] === Object(obj[key])) newObj[key] = removeEmpty(obj[key]);
    else if (obj[key] !== '')               newObj[key] = obj[key];
  });
  return newObj;
}
```

```js
var obj = {
  Sale: {
    homeownerExemption: '',
    lastContractDate: '',
    lastSaleBookNumber: undefined,
    lastSaleDate: null,
    saleType: 'Full Sale',
    salesPrice: '785000',
    salesPriceCode: 'Sales Price Will Be Computed',
    seller1FName: '',
    seller1IdCode: '',
    seller1FirstName: 'Steve',
    seller1LastName: 'Miller',
    seller2FirstName: '',
    seller2LastName: '',
    transferType: 'Grant Deed',
    lastTransactionRecordingDate: '7/8/2021'
  },
  contact: [{
    name: 'Tom',
    age: '',
    sex: 'male'
  }]
};


const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
  let newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (obj[key] === Object(obj[key])) newObj[key] = removeEmpty(obj[key]);
    else if (!(obj[key] === "" || obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined)) newObj[key] = obj[key];
  });
  return newObj;
};

let test = removeEmpty(obj)

console.log(test)
```

Comment: in your code you also transform the type of `obj.contact` into an **object** whereas it was previously an **array** , It's desired ?

Comment: and if in the end a parent object only contains empty objects, should it also disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `obj[key] === ""`, then it's not equal to null or undefined.  So the second and third parts of your condition pass.

Try

```
if (!(obj[key] === "" || obj[key] === null || obj[key] === undefined))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parenthesize the condition properly. Don't be cheap out on the parens, they're free! A reasonable way could be like this:

```
((obj[key] !== '') || (obj[key] !== null) || (obj[key] !== undefined))
```

Your condition has an extra `(` after second `||`.

Comment: Apart from pointing out the extra parens, your suggestion won't solve the problem. In fact, it won't make any difference what so ever.